# FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error when running batch class

Tags: apex, batch

I have a batch class which updates Opportunities when Product2 Custom field value changes to **EAL**. I want to send the failed records to my email ID. When ever I ran this batch it is giving Internal Salesforce Error and I am not able to find any issue in Debugs. Can any one please help me  with this.
**Error : FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error**

**Note : If I remove Database.Stateful i don't see this issue. but the problem is when I remove Databas.stateful the Failure Ids are null**

Class :

```
global class Batch_Product_class implements Database.Batchable < sObject > , Database.Stateful {


    List < ID > Pids = new List < ID > ();
    Set < ID > SuccessIds = new Set < ID > ();
    global Set < ID > FailureIds = new Set < ID > ();
    Set < Id > allIds = new Set < Id > ();

    global String log = '';
    Database.SaveResult[] srList;
    global Batch_Product_class(List < ID > pfIist) {

        Pids = pfIist; // sending ids from Trigger

    }

    //Quuery method.
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // Query Opportunity line items
        return DataBase.getQueryLocator([select Id, PricebookEntry.Product2Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Custom_field__c, OpportunityId, TotalPrice from OpportunityLineItem where PricebookEntry.Product2Id IN: Pids]);

    }

    //Execute Method.
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List < OpportunityLineItem > scope_Oli) {

        Map < Id, List < OpportunityLineItem >> OppOppLineItemMap = new Map < Id, List < OpportunityLineItem >> ();
        Map < Id, Set < Id >> OppProdFamilyMap = new Map < Id, Set < Id >> ();

        for (OpportunityLineItem OL: scope_Oli) {

            if (OppOppLineItemMap.keyset().contains(OL.OpportunityId))
                OppOppLineItemMap.get(OL.OpportunityId).add(OL);
            else {
                OppOppLineItemMap.put(OL.OpportunityId, new List < OpportunityLineItem > ());
                OppOppLineItemMap.get(OL.OpportunityId).add(OL);
            }

            if (!OppProdFamilyMap.keyset().contains(OL.PricebookEntry.Product2Id))
                OppProdFamilyMap.put(OL.PricebookEntry.Product2Id, new Set < Id > ());

            OppProdFamilyMap.get(OL.PricebookEntry.Product2Id).add(OL.OpportunityId);
        }

        List < Opportunity > updateopps = new List < Opportunity > ();

        List < OpportunityLineItem > AllOpLines = [select Id, PricebookEntry.Product2Id, PricebookEntry.Product2.Custom_field__c, OpportunityId, TotalPrice from OpportunityLineItem where
            OpportunityId IN: OppOppLineItemMap.keyset() AND Id NOT IN: scope_Oli
        ];


        for (OpportunityLineItem opLI: AllOpLines) {
            OppOppLineItemMap.get(opLI.OpportunityId).add(opLI);
        }

        for (Id lst: OppOppLineItemMap.keyset()) {
            Opportunity Opp = new Opportunity();
            Opp.Id = lst;

            Opp.EAmount__c = 0;


            for (OpportunityLineItem OLI: OppOppLineItemMap.get(lst)) {

                System.Debug('OLI.Name####' + OLI);

                if (OLI.PricebookEntry.Product2.Custom_field__c == 'EAL') {

                    Opp.EAmount__c = Opp.EAmount__c + OLI.Totalprice;
                    System.Debug('Entered EAL');

                }

            }
            allIds.add(Opp.Id);
            updateopps.add(Opp);
        }

        if (updateopps.size() > 0) {

            srList = Database.update(updateopps, false);



            // Iterate through the Save Results 
            for (Database.SaveResult sr: srList) {
                // fetch all success DML id's in this set
                if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                    System.debug('Entered Sucess>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>..');
                    SuccessIds.add(sr.getId());

                }
            }


            // one set has all id's, other has id's that were successfully updated. So compare them both to get //the id's that failed to update
            for (Id i: allIds) {
                if (!SuccessIds.contains(i))
                    FailureIds.add(i);
            }

            system.debug('######## successful ids :: ' + SuccessIds);
            system.debug('######## failed ids :: ' + FailureIds);
        }


    }

    //Finish method to execute at last.
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String[] Body = new String[0];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail;
        for (Id ids: FailureIds) {

            Body.add(ids);


        }
        String result = String.join(Body, '<br/>');
        mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {
            'abc@gmail.com'
        };
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSubject('Failure Report ');

        mail.setHtmlBody('Failure Report' + '::::::' + result);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > {
            mail
        };
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);



    }


}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't serialize all types of data. If you include a non-serializable data type in your class' storage, you'll get an Internal Server Error.

It appears that your problem is most likely the `Database.SaveResult[] srList;`, if memory serves me correctly. Move the declaration of the `srList` to inside of the `execute` method.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, your response was helpful to me. 

We were using Map<Id, Database.saveResult> declared as a class variable, to keep collecting errors in each batch (execute method) using Database.stateful interface. It was working until few days back, but suddenly stopped working, I changed Database.saveResult to String and it worked.

I am wondering if there is any list of serializable objects in Salesforce documentation, so that in future it can help.

Comment: @NitishSinghal there is no such list, unfortunately. Some trial and error is necessary. I have a feeling it's a moving target, which is why Salesforce doesn't document which are unsafe. I generally recommend not serializing anything from the Database namespace, but you'll also find other things that will break. When possible, use a wrapper class or primitives only (sobjects are also okay).

Comment: I realized from this link below, that in some situations, objects can't be serialized if error is happening in managed package. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_json_overview.htm